# iphone address book not saving records

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a view controller which creates new records for the first visit with a new entry.  Unfortunately, the new record is not being stored.  I can tell this when I navigate to the prior page and return, the new record is not displayed.  I have displayed "user", which is an NSString separately.  I also get a NSLog message that there are no unsaved changes (see if statement below). Attached is my code:

(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

person = ABPersonCreate();

bool didSet = ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, user, &error);

if (!didSet) {
      NSLog(@"the RecordSetValue error is %@", error);
}

ABMutableMultiValueRef multiURL =    ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiURL,user,kABPersonHomePageLabel,NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty, multiURL, &error);

CFRelease(multiURL);

//save values to address book

NSLog(@"does address book have unsaved changes?  %@",ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook) ? @"YES" : @"NO");

bool didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

if (!didSave) {
    NSLog(@"the save to address book error is %@", error);
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a `ABPerson` record, but never added it to your address book using `ABAddressBookAddRecord`. That would also be why `ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges` is returning `NO`.

Comment: Thanks!  Wish Apple put that in the examples in their address book programming guide.  Now I see the records.  However, when I exit the view controller via navigation and return I get a count of 0 from the ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople command.  Would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: The documentation for ABPersonCreate() specifically mentions ABAddressBookAddRecord. You should make a habit of glancing at documentation for functions you haven't used before. ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople returns a "snapshot" of the address book. If there were no records before you aded yours, then it would have a count of zero. If you want it to return an array containing your newly added record, call it after saving the address book. P.S. If my answer answered your question, accept it :)